# Content Security Policy reject XSS attacks in v-html

Tags: vue.js, content-security-policy

I was expecting that having a **Response Header**: `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` in my Nuxt.js .vue file. With my snippet below

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-html="xss"></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { xss: '<b onmouseover=alert("Wufff!")>click me!</b>' }
  }
}
</script>
```

I was expecting that hovering on the `span` from the browser will not result to an `alert` but it still does despite the `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I cant comment so I am posting answer as I fully dont understand the question (i heard xhtml exist, never heard about vhtml). `<span>` doesnt protect against XSS attack.This triggers xss.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title></head>
    <body>
        <span ><img src=x onerror=alert(1)></img></span>
</html>
```

Don't use `<span>` as a mitigating measure. You should read what the `unsafe-inline` policy does. It allows as it name says any script on that page from the attacker. So, you should never use `unsafe-inline` to mitigate XSS attack. Use only `self` or other sources that you trust. In nutshell, `unsafe-inline` is a blessing for hackers. As its name says its an unsafe policy

This topic is more suited on security.stackexchange.com
[image: alert(1)]

Comment: Are you saying that I should just remove `unsafe-inline` in my `Content-Security-Policy`?

Comment: OF course. Thats dangerous as its name says (unsafe), instead use self

Answer (score 0):

**nuxt-helmet** module did the trick for me. Just add below snippet in **nuxt.config.js**

```
   helmet: {
     contentSecurityPolicy: {
       directives: {
         defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
         scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-eval'"]
       }
     }
   }
```